# How develop azure function locally to subscribe to Cosmos change feed using managed Identity

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-managed-identity

I have the following function to subscribe to Cosmos Change feed:

```
  [FunctionName("CosmosDB_ChangeFeed")]
        public void Cosmos_ChangeFeed([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName:"%databaseName%",
            containerName:"%containerName%",
            LeaseContainerName="%leaseContainerName%",
            Connection = "CosmosDB")] IReadOnlyList<PocoItem>input)
```

This is functioning as expected when the function is running in Azure.

Question: How do I get this to work locally in order to develop the function?

The code is using the latest version of *Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB* (4.2.0), which supports using managed identity to access Cosmos DB. The manage identity has to be assigned to the "*Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor*" role in order for this to work. Additionally, there is a specific way that the "Connection" Property of the CosmosDBTrigger needs to be set in the ConnectionStrings in the Configurations. The *Connection* property value in the CosmosDBTrigger in the code, is used as follows in the Function Application Connection Strings configurations:

[image]

In order to run this locally I have assigned my Identity to the "*Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor*" role, in the same way as was done to permission the Azure Function System-Assigned Identity to the Cosmos Database. While my account is obviously not a managed Identity, I see no other way to provide a similar security context.

I get the following error when attempting to start the function app locally: *Exception: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No Managed Identity endpoint found*.

Is User-assigned managed identity supported?
I could not find any documentation to indicate this or otherwise. I did try to configure in the function deployed to Azure as I thought user-assigned managed identity might be a way forward when running locally. No Luck.

References to get this to work in azure:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w002dYaP9mw
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/under-the-hood-of-the-new-azure-functions-extension-for-azure-cosmos-db/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not Cosmos DB specific but more about "How do I use Azure Functions with MSI locally".

Because the Function App runs locally, you can still use MSI but you cannot use the `credential` configuration to `managedidentity` because really it's not running within the Azure Resource, it's your machine (unless you have an identity mapped to your environment for which you also provided permissions, see the last link in References).

You can either have another Azure AD Identity for local development, and add a Secret to it, so locally, so when you are locally defining the configuration, you'd have something like this in your `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "Values": {
    "CosmosDB__accountEndpoint": "https:.....",
    "CosmosDB__clientId": "The Azure AD App Id",
    "CosmosDB__tenantId": "The Azure AD App Tenant Id",
    "CosmosDB__clientSecret": "The secret generated for this App Id"
  }
}
```

References:

- https://www.youtube.com/live/brB4UHpIWiM?feature=share&t=933
- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#local-development-with-identity-based-connections

Comment: Thats partially correct. You can use your own credentials (VSCode, VS) to authenticate without an app registration and secrets in local.settings.json
while for cosmos you just have to be logged in via azcli or your IDE and have CosmosConnectionOptions__accountEndpoint in the local.settings.json (without providing `__credential` property.
a full example for service bus can be found here.
https://www.michaelscollier.com/azure-function-secretless-extensions-first-experience/